# How can I optimize this nginx proxy cache configuration?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I want to cache all `*.html` files in a Nginx reverse proxy, So I added the config:

```
# Original configuration
location = / {
    proxy_pass   http://192.168.12.12:91;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

# Added for cache
location ~ \.html {
    proxy_pass   http://192.168.12.12:91;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_cache cache_one;
    proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1m;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
    expires     1m;
}
```

Repeat twice `proxy_pass` and `proxy_set_header` feel bad

How can I optimize this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move this configuration

```
proxy_pass              http://192.168.12.12:91;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

into a separate file called `proxy.conf` and then include it in the right place

```
location = / {
    include proxy.conf;
}

# Added for cache
location ~ \.html {
    include proxy.conf;

    proxy_cache cache_one;
    proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1m;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
    expires     1m;
}
```